# Styling dynamic content

Tags: php, html, css, sql, styling

I currently have a simple application which is fully functional and queries data using php and sql. However, I am struggling to style the website as attributes don't seem to be applying. I am using the following code to wrap my searchbar, dropdown and submit button in a class, with the intentions of centering said class and putting a border around it. Here is the code I am using in the webpage:

```
IF (!isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    //drop down
    $sqlDrop = "SELECT DISTINCT ID as contID, Name as contName from w_Continent order by contName;";
    $stmtDrop = $db->query($sqlDrop);
//Start a form
    echo "<div class='searchWrap'>";
    echo "<form action='listCont.php' method='get'>\n";
//Start a select box
    echo "<select name='contID'>\n";
    echo "<option value=\"0\" disabled selected>Select Continent</option>";
//Loop through all continents
    while ($dropdownVar = $stmtDrop->fetchObject()) {
//Display each one as an option in the drop down
        echo "\t\t<option value='{$dropdownVar->contID}'> {$dropdownVar->contName} </option>\n";
    }//end loop
echo "</select>";
// Put filter textbox here
    echo "<input name='countFilter' type='text' placeholder='filter by country name'/>";
// display submit button
    echo "<input name ='submit' type='submit' value='Search' />\n";
    //end form
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";
```

And here is the code used in stylesheet:

```
.searchWrap {
    border-style: solid;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Apologies for big blocks of code, just I need everything which div is wrapped in to show relevant code around the issue. Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: `.searchWrap { border: 1px solid black` }  ?

Comment: Ah I went wrong by not assigning a numeric value to the border, just a border style. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
.searchWrap {
      border-style: solid; 
      text-align:center;
}
```

to

```
 .searchWrap {
      border:1px solid #ccc; 
      text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't see that. NP :)